# Can't get past Launch Startup Repair through nothing

Tags: windows, boot

I turned my computer on the other morning and it had two options on the screen. Launch Startup Repair and Start Windows normally. I clicked the normal. Then it goes back to the Launch Startup Repair screen.

I have clicked on both of them several times and still couldn’t fix the issue; I even went under the System Restore option in the safe mode and tried a few times. I finally got it restored on one of the options on a single day. There were no more restore points available.

When it logged off and logged back on it went back to the Launch Startup Repair.

From my research on the internet most of it says that Windows will have to be restored. I have no problem doing that but I have over 1000 pictures and numerous documents that I desperately need.

So, my question is can the system be repaired in any way? If not is there anyway for me to get the pictures and documents off the computer?

Comment: It would help if you made this question clear.  We only need to know your question.  Please format your question so people can actually read it.

Comment: @Chris: Grab a windows installation disk, boot from it, enter the recovery mode and then do a disk check. You will be able to copy your files using any Windows/Linux live disk

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows 7 this is what has worked most often for me:

1. Put in your windows disk
2. Instead if installing Windows again, there is an option along the way to repair windows.
3. After it tries to repair itself it will give you an option to open a terminal, do that.
4. Type `bootrec.exe` and it will tell you about three options. Run them all. I think that one is `bootrec.exe \fixboot`
5. Restart your computer. If it doesn't start normally, I recommend using a [linux live usb](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to get the important files from your computer then reinstall windows.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, Windows repair should fix most booting issues. Try what Jeff suggests and possibly a fix will do the trick.

Alternatively, after BIOS screen, press F8 and choose to boot on safe mode.

That way you will have access to the files you need and possibly copy them to a safer location like an external disk considering they are mostly media related.

After copying the files, go to **Start-> Run and type msconfig**.

Ensure that only the option "Load basic Windows services" is checked.

Then restart your system and see the result.

If it boots, go to **msconfig** again and recheck all the previous settings.
If it doesn't boot and the system repair doesn't work, consider reinstalling Windows from the scratch.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like a failing hard drive. If you have an install CD for your operating system, you will want to insert it and run some repairs and that hopefully that will fix the issue.

Comment: "run some repairs" — can you be more specific please?